# So my bullet prefab shows trail when dragged into the scene But not when I play it

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer

So when in scene mode the bullet prefab shows the trails but when I hit the play button it doesn't show any trails whatsoever.
I am trying to make a top down shooter with unity. I am new to this, please help much appreciated.

[While playing it doesn't show the trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvguV.png)

[When in scene mode it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elnun.png)

[Trail renderer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFalc.png)

Comment: Hi, while theres some great explanation of the issue, we really need a [mcve] to diagnose whats going on

Comment: Could be the sorting order. If you remove the background, do you see the trail?

Comment: @iggy yes it works when i remove the background, how could that be?

Comment: Make sure your Z axiss between the camera, and the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the order of the trail renderer in `Trail Renderer > Additional Settings > Order in Layer`.

For an older version of Unity layer ordering variables are not exposed in the inspector. You can write a custom script that sets the sorting layer / order.

```
public class RendererSortingLayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sortingLayerName;
    public int sortingOrder;

    void Awake()
    {
        Renderer renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.sortingLayerName = sortingLayerName;
        renderer.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find the trail renderer settings...help

Comment: @SagarRawat try the solution for an older version.